# Clear default form value if left empty by user

Tags: html, forms

I am using a form with default values used as label placeholders, the form is using validation and, if the user leaves the optional mobile number then validation fails, as it reads the default value.

I would like to know if it is possible to clear the default values upon submission of the form?

I cannot use HTML5 `placeholder` due to IE7 compatibility requirements.

Comment: How do you set the default value?

Comment: Why not just use placeholder attributes?

Comment: cant use placeholder as site must work in ie7 :(

Comment: <input type="text" value="something">

Comment: are you processing the results with php? the best thing to do would be something on the server side (a simple check -- if the passed value equals the placeholder value, discard it). any javascript solution would still pass the placeholder values to the server if a user has javascript disabled.

Comment: a javascript solution would be ideal as the validation itself is javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) attribute:

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value === "555-5555"){
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = "";
  }else{
    alert("Submitted!");
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
 <input type="text" value="555-5555"/>
</form>
```

It will populate the input field with an initial value, which will be used if left unaltered by the user when the form is submitted. So, check whether what is submitted equals the default with JavaScript when the form submits (ideally, you'd want to do this server-side, but this is for the sake of simplicity).

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, there is an attribute for input tags i.e. defaultValue

So, If you are appying validations using javascript / jQuery, just read the defaultValue attribute of tag.

In Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('emailId').defaultValue; // To get default value
document.getElementById('emailId').value; // To get changed value
```

In jQuery:

```
$('#emailId').prop('defaultValue'); // To get default value
$('#emailId').val();                // To get changed value
```

You can then compare the default value with changed value.